# How to kill the Chrome driver process once the browser is closed with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I made a stand-alone GUI for my Selenium project, and I noticed that after using it for a while, I had 10+ chrome drivers opened in task manager. I realize this is because driver.quit() is never called. I need to make it to where in the event that the chrome browser is closed, the driver quits. How do I do this?

edit: I can make the driver quit once the process is done, but sometimes I want to close the browser and quit the process in the middle of it running, meaning the code that quits the driver wouldn't be reached. This is why I need to quit the driver in the event that the chrome window is closed.

edit: Ill give an example:

```
public static void runJoinGroup(String groupLink, String accounts) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(accounts);
        process(sc);
        launchBrowser();
        while (x < users.size()) {
            login(users.get(x), pass.get(x));
            x++;
            joinGroup(groupLink);
            logout();
        }
    }
```

this is the method that one of the buttons on my GUI executes when pressed. I could quit the driver after the method is finished running, like this:

```
public static void runJoinGroup(String groupLink, String accounts) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(accounts);
        process(sc);
        launchBrowser();
        while (x < users.size()) {
            login(users.get(x), pass.get(x));
            x++;
            joinGroup(groupLink);
            logout();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
```

However, if I close the browser before it is finished logging into all the accounts (before x>=users.size()), driver.quit() will never be executed and I will still have the chrome driver running in the background. This is what I am trying to prevent.

edit: Here is a clear, reproducible example:

```
public static void example() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            driver.get("google.com");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    driver.quit();

    }
```

This example code visits google.com and then sleeps for 5 seconds 100 times. If I decide to press the 'X' button before google.com has been visited 100 times, the line containing driver.quit() will not have been reached, and therefore the chrome driver will continue to run in the background. This is what I am trying to prevent. I want to make it to where if I decide to close out of the chrome browser (by pressing the 'X' button at the top right hand corner of the browser) BEFORE the process is finished, it will quit the driver.

Here's an image of how the GUI works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqLDx.jpg (Zoom in to see the labels I made).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226730/discussion-on-question-by-grant-martin-how-to-kill-the-chrome-driver-process-onc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surrounding all of my methods with

```
try{
    method()
} finally{
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ChromeDriver.exe")
}
```

ended up solving the issue. After the method is either done being run or some exception caused it to stop running (like closing the browser), all instances of ChromeDriver.exe are killed.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure geckodriver is killed I use the following code snippet:

```
private static final String TASKLIST = "tasklist";
private static final String KILL = "taskkill /F /IM ";

public boolean isProcessRunning(String serviceName) throws Exception {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(TASKLIST);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

       System.out.println(line);
        if (line.contains(serviceName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void killProcess(String serviceName) throws Exception {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(KILL + serviceName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you close the browser, Selenium will throw an exception which causes the method to pre-emptively return. You should add a `try...finally` block to be sure that closing the chrome driver exists cleanly whether or not this exception throws:

```
try {
    method();
} finally {
    driver.quit();
}
```

This assumes that `driver` is in scope. So add the `try...finally` wherever it is available. If you are doing this in a lot of places, think about refactoring where you initialize the driver so you can minimize how much you have to repeat the `try...finally` block.

Answer (score -1):

Open console and execute the below command, it will work and kill all pending process related to chrome.

taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f